# Fun Math Topics, Activities, and Riddles

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I'll be teaching college algebra this summer. Last summer when I taught the same course, I finished lectures early (thanks mainly to LaTeX's Beamer package). I want to fill these gaps this time around.

To show students that advanced mathematics can be fun, and to mainly keep them engaged and focused during the *summer* course, I'd love to spend 10-20 in the middle of most lectures doing some riddles and paradoxes (e.g., the "Monty Hall Problem"), demonstrating a few things from, say, topology (e.g., by using Möbius strips), discussing nonintuitive theorems found in advanced mathematics (e.g., the Banach-Tarski Theorem, $\operatorname{card } \mathbb{N} = \operatorname{card } \mathbb{Z} = \operatorname{card } \mathbb{Q}$, etc.), and so on.

Obviously, *I don't expect the students to actually learn this extra stuff.* I just want to insert fun things in some of my lectures.

QUESTIONS:

- What are some interesting topics, riddles, and paradoxes to discuss?
- What are some fun math activities/experiments to demonstrate?
- What are some books that I should consider looking through to find other ideas?

Comment: The first time I saw [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVVfs4zKrgk), I enjoyed it. It also serves as a good illustration.

Comment: Yes, that's a very sweet video. I remember the first time I watched it too. I'll definitely consider it. Thanks for the suggestion, Clayton.

Comment: Also, [this page of riddles](http://mathriddles.williams.edu/) is a bit of a gem if you ask me, with varying difficulties.

Answer (score 3):

My all-time favorite collection of mathematical puzzles are two books by Peter Winkler:
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/1568813368](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568813368)
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/1568812019](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568812019)

This is also good:
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/0486281523](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486281523)

Volumes 1-4 of this book are full of fun games (although the theory might be a little much for summer schoolers):
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/1568811306](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568811306)

And here's a cute video explaining the nature of exponential growth, lol:
http://youtu.be/Q4gTV4r0zRs

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the paradoxes, I recommend the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). For most people it is truly an amazing result, and the phenonemon even has applications in cryptography (the *birthday attack*).